# help me understand JS execution on onclick event of button

Tags: asp.net, javascript

```
<input type="button" name="reset"
       onclick="return ValidateValue(); __doPostBack('ApplyBtn','')" />
```

The above is the code generated for asp server button button control on browser.

Now my query is that irrespective of `ValidateValue()` returning true/false `__doPostBack('ApplyBtn','')` function is not showing any effect for me.

My understanding is that string passed to onclick acts like function body, and `return` will from first function will return control preventing second function from execution.
Is that correct ?

Please provide helpful inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct...and it's easily fixed :), instead of this:

```
return ValidateValue();
```

Do this:

```
if(!ValidateValue()) return false;
```

This way you only abort early if there is a reason to abort, otherwise you continue executing the rest.